# GSL library issue

Tags: libraries, gnu

I have a problem when including gnu library in a c++ script:

```c++
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_sf_bessel.h>

int main (void)
{
    double x = 5.0;
    double y = gsl_sf_bessel_J0 (x);
    printf ("J0(%g) = %.18e\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

After running in the shell:

```
g++ -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm -o prova prova.cpp
```

I get:

```
/tmp/cc4EUwzZ.o: In function `main':
prova.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `gsl_sf_bessel_J0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I also get the same output if I type:

```
g++ -o prova prova.cpp
```

or

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/gsl -lgsl -o prova prova.cpp
```

It seems that I am not linking the library properly.

If I type

```
pkg-config --cflags gsl
```

I get

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Don't get me wrong, i don't have any knowledge about this but is there an inconsistency here :

`g++ -Wall -I/usr/include/gsl -lgsl -o prova prova.cpp` and

`-I/usr/local/include`

One of them points /usr/local/ the other /usr/include/.

Comment: Please check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588607/g-unable-to-link-libgsl